# How to sum user input in a while loop-JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Below I am trying to sum the results of the user input. The program runs fine except that when it loops, the user inputs do not get added. Can you help point out what is incorrect?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

double NICKEL  = .05;
double DIME    = .10;
double QUARTER = .25;

//Other declarations
double coin  = 0; //to hold input from user
double total = 0;

while(coin <= 1 ){
    System.out.print("Insert coin: ");
    coin = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if(coin==NICKEL || coin==DIME || coin==QUARTER){
        total += coin;
        System.out.println("Amount entered: " +coin);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid!");

        System.out.print("Insert coin: ");
        coin = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: change `while(coin <= 1 )` to `while(total <= 1)`

Comment: How do you know that the inputs are not addd? You don't print the total anywhere. Use your debugger to diagnose such simple problems: you'll save months of your precious life.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail what you are trying to do? And how do you know total does not contain your sum? Have you tried debugging your application?

Comment: You should put a print of the `total` AFTER the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
System.out.println("Amount entered: " +coin);
```

`coin` should be `total`. As it is, you are never printing out the value of `total`, but it is increasing.

As noted in the comments this loop will continue until the coin that is entered happened to be greater than `1`.

Comment: `coin` is correct. The OP is displaying the value entered, not what the total is

Comment: @Ascalonian There is no evidence of that. 'Amount entered' could be a running total OR the most recent 'coin'. However, it is clear that the OP thinks the total should be appearing... somewhere. And that is the only place currently where that might happen.

Comment: Doesn't the word "entered" imply a value entered, not amount tallied? Either way, you are correct - `total` needs to be displayed. The OP should just make it a print out after the while loop.

Comment: @Ascalonian Depends how you interpret 'entered'. Is it "amount entered on the last loop of the program" or "amount entered so far during the execution of the program"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to print out the total at the end of the loop. You are currently printing out the coin values as they are entered, but you will need to put`System.out.println("Total: " + total);` somewhere in your code following the `while` loop.

As a side note, in the `else` block, you are calling `coin = keyboard.nextDouble();` again, but that value will never be used before the loop ends. Assuming the user enters an invalid value, it is sufficient to only notify them of the error. Then, when the loop starts again, the value of coin will be set.

Also, it looks to me like your loop will run forever. Since you always reset the value of coin to `NICKLE, DIME` or `QUARTER`, the loop will never stop. That's a problem. From your code, it looks to me like you want to stop the loop when the user has entered values that sum up to at least a dollar. If that is the case, the `while` loop condition should be `while(total <= 1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of you need wright amount value. Not coin value. `System.out.println("Amount entered: " +total );`,

Secondly your while loop can cause problems. When users input > 1 your second input call run `coin = keyboard.nextDouble();` . If again users input > 1 while not work. Check first, then you must assign the value of the coins.
And you dont need again call `coin = keyboard.nextDouble();`

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double NICKEL  = .05;
        double DIME    = .10;
        double QUARTER = .25;

        //Other declarations
        double coin  = 0; //to hold input from user
        double total = 0;

        while(coin <= 1 ){
            System.out.print("Insert coin: ");
            double key = keyboard.nextDouble();

            if(key==NICKEL || key==DIME || key==QUARTER){
                coin = key;
                total += coin;
                System.out.println("Amount entered: " +total);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid!");
            }
        }
```